# ModSecurity error on wordpress wp-login rules

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, mod-security, brute-force-attacks

I have made i ModSecurity rule for apache to protect wordpress, but it have some error, so please suggest me some modification to work it fine.

```
# This has to be global, cannot exist within a directory or location clause . . .
        SecAction "id:7157150,phase:1,nolog,pass,initcol:ip=%{REMOTE_ADDR},initcol:user=%{REMOTE_ADDR}"
        <Location /wp-login.php>
                # Setup brute force detection. 

                # React if block flag has been set.
                SecRule user:bf_block "@gt 0" "id:7157151,deny,status:401,log,msg:'ip address blocked for 5 minutes, more than 15 login attempts in 3 minutes.'"

                # Setup Tracking.  On a successful login, a 302 redirect is performed, a 200 indicates login failed.
                SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^302" "id:7157152,phase:5,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
                SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" "id:7157153,phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,deprecatevar:ip.bf_counter=1/180"
                SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 15" "id:7157154,t:none,setvar:user.bf_block=1,expirevar:user.bf_block=300,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
        </location>
```

**Currently its show these error**

The system could not validate the new Apache configuration because httpd exited with a nonzero value. Apache produced the following error:

```
AH00526: Syntax error on line 12 of /usr/local/apache/conf/modsec_vendor_configs/mynew/rs_wordpress.conf:
ModSecurity: Metadata actions (id, rev, msg, tag, severity, ver, accuracy, maturity, logdata) can only be specified by chain starter rules.
```

**If you don't know answer than please don't mark as duplicate or down vote.**

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
 SecRule ip:bf_counter "@gt 15" "id:7157154,t:none,setvar:user.bf_block=1,expirevar:user.bf_block=300,setvar:ip.bf_counter=0"
```

... does not need an id:xxxx value since it is part of a chain.

So it, in a sense, "inherits" the action ID of: 7157153 from the "chain starter rule":

```
SecRule RESPONSE_STATUS "^200" "id:7157153,phase:5,chain,t:none,nolog,pass,setvar:ip.bf_counter=+1,deprecatevar:ip.bf_counter=1/180"
```